# c++ friend inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, friend

I understand that `friend` is not inherited. I have classes `Parent Person Child`. Parent and Person are friends of each other. Parent has the following PROTECTED function...

```
class Person
{
    friend class Parent;
    public:
        Parent * parent;
}

class Parent
{
    friend class Person;
    protected:
        virtual void Answer() = 0;
}

class Child : public Parent
{
    void Answer()
    {
        std::cout << "Child!" << endl;
    }
}
```

My question is, if friendship is not inherited, how am I able to have the following...?
(Person has a pointer to Parent)

```
Person person;
Child child;
person.parent->Answer();
```

Why is the output of this Child!, and it does not throw a runtime error when trying to access a virtual function?

I am confused as to how the child's function is being implemented, and the program is not erroring on run time since I would anticipate that it is trying to call Parent's virtual Answer function.

Comment: Do you have any inheritance here? i.e. `class Child: public Parent` in you Child class definition?

Comment: You are not calling any function on `Child` as I see in the Q.

Comment: Rather than describing your code, please post a trivial (but complete) code snippet.  That way, we can all be clear about what your inheritance/friendship relationship is when answering.

Comment: @Als So because I am calling Answer from type Parent, it's ok? Even though it's virtual and implemented by type Child?

Comment: You need to show the code you are trying to figure out, then we can explain it easily. Without, we are lost.  Edit your question to include the small but relevant samples.

Comment: Without the code this is like shooting in the dark and i hate to do that because i might end up shooting my own foot.Post an code sample.

Comment: See my update. I assumed that you initialise `Person::parent` somewhere with something that points to a `Child`.

Comment: error: 'virtual void Parent::Answer()' is protected

Comment: Even after fixing the code, I cannot get that to compile. I really don't think you can do what you claim to be doing.

Comment: See [here](http://ideone.com/NjKLh)

Comment: @juanchopanza: From the context, I'm pretty sure `person.parent->Answer();` was meant as `this->parent->Answer();` or at least from within some `Person` context (perhaps not referencing `this` but a different `Person` object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not accessing `Child::Answer` but `Parent::Answer` here, that's okay, because `Parent` is your friend. The fact that this is a `Child` object doesn't matter for that. However, it matters for what method will actually be invoked at runtime. Since `Parent::Answer` is `virtual`, overriding it with `Child::Answer` means that callers who have no clue what a `Child` is, will still be calling `Child::Answer` even when `Child` is accessed through a `Parent` reference or pointer (there is a layer of indirection that resolves the appropriate function at runtime).

You could even compile this before even implementing `Child` and later link against this `.o` file, handing it a `Child` instance, disguised as a `Parent&` or `Parent*`. `Person` will never have had the chance to even *know* that there is something called `Child` but still be able to "find" the correct implementation. That's the power of dynamic binding.

Comment: What child object?? The call is to the Person's Parent object.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I answered before OP added the declaration+implementation of the three classes. The question specifically asked how `Child::Answer` could be called from within a `Person` context.